# Unable to parse JSON? Or is it JavaScript text (How to parse a custom config file)

Tags: javascript, python, json, powershell, parsing

I am trying to parse what I originally suspected was a JSON config file from a server.

After some attempts I was able to navigate and collapse the sections within Notepad++ when I selected the formatter as JavaScript.

However I am stuck on how I can convert/parse this data to JSON/another format, no online tools have been able to help with this.

How can I parse this text? Ideally I was trying to use PowerShell, but Python would also be an option if I can figure out how I can even begin the conversion.

**For example, I am trying to parse out each of the servers, ie. test1, test2, test3 and get the data listed within each block.**

Here is a sample of the config file format:

```
servername {
  store {
    servers {
      * {
        value<>
        port<>
        folder<C:\windows>
        monitor<yes>
        args<-T -H>
        xrg<store>
        wysargs<-t -g -b>
        accept_any<yes>
        pdu_length<23622>
      }
      test1 {
        name<test1>
        port<123>
        root<c:\test>
        monitor<yes>
      }
      test2 {
        name<test2>
        port<124>
        root<c:\test>
        monitor<yes>
      }
      test3 {
        name<test3>
        port<125>
        root<c:\test>
        monitor<yes>
      }
    }
    senders
    timeout<30>
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why your server can't supply you with JSON?

Comment: That's neither JSON nor JavaScript, looks like a DSL for a config management system or a web server perhaps. Can you say more about where it comes from?

Comment: Using some RegEx you could try to convert that to JSON, then use `ConvertFrom-Json` to turn it into PowerShell objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with an even simpler solution than my [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72241688/7571258) which uses **PowerShell** code only.

Using the [RegEx alternation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions) `|` we combine all token patterns into a single pattern and use [named subexpressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named-matched-subexpressions) to determine which one has actually matched.

The rest of the code is structurally similar to the C#/PS version.

```sh
using namespace System.Text.RegularExpressions

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Function ConvertFrom-ServerData {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] [string] $InputObject
    )

    begin {
        # Key can consist of anything except whitespace and < > { }
        $keyPattern = '[^\s<>{}]+'

        # Order of the patterns is important 
        $pattern = (
            "(?<IntKey>$keyPattern)\s*<(?<IntValue>\d+)>",
            "(?<TrueKey>$keyPattern)\s*<yes>",
            "(?<FalseKey>$keyPattern)\s*<no>",
            "(?<StrKey>$keyPattern)\s*<(?<StrValue>.*?)>",
            "(?<ObjectBegin>$keyPattern)\s*{",
            "(?<ObjectEnd>})",
            "(?<KeyOnly>$keyPattern)",
            "(?<Invalid>\S+)"  # any non-whitespace sequence that didn't match the valid patterns
        ) -join '|'
    }

    process {
        # Output is an ordered hashtable
        $curObject = $outputObject = [ordered] @{}

        # A stack is used to keep track of nested objects.
        $stack = [Collections.Stack]::new()
        
        # For each pattern match
        foreach( $match in [RegEx]::Matches( $InputObject, $pattern, [RegexOptions]::Multiline ) ) {

            # Get the RegEx groups that have actually matched.
            $matchGroups = $match.Groups.Where{ $_.Success -and $_.Name.Length -gt 1 }

            $key = $matchGroups[ 0 ].Value

            switch( $matchGroups[ 0 ].Name ) {
                'ObjectBegin' {
                    $child = [ordered] @{} 
                    $curObject[ $key ] = $child
                    $stack.Push( $curObject )
                    $curObject = $child
                    break                    
                }
                'ObjectEnd' {
                    if( $stack.Count -eq 0 ) {
                        Write-Error -EA Stop "Parse error: Curly braces are unbalanced. There are more '}' than '{' in config data."
                    }
                    $curObject = $stack.Pop()
                    break
                }
                'IntKey' {
                    $value = $matchGroups[ 1 ].Value 
                    $intValue = 0
                    $curObject[ $key ] = if( [int]::TryParse( $value, [ref] $intValue ) ) { $intValue } else { $value }
                    break
                }
                'TrueKey' {
                    $curObject[ $key ] = $true
                    break
                }
                'FalseKey' {
                    $curObject[ $key ] = $false
                    break
                }
                'StrKey' {
                    $value = $matchGroups[ 1 ].Value
                    $curObject[ $key ] = $value
                    break
                }
                'KeyOnly' {
                    $curObject[ $key ] = $null
                    break
                }
                'Invalid' {
                    Write-Warning "Invalid token at index $($match.Index): $key"
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if( $stack.Count -gt 0 ) {
            Write-Error "Parse error: Curly braces are unbalanced. There are more '{' than '}' in config data."
        }

        $outputObject  # Implicit output
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```sh
$sampleData = @'
test-server {
    store {
      servers {
        * {
          value<>
          port<>
          folder<C:\windows> monitor<yes>
          args<-T -H>
          xrg<store>
          wysargs<-t -g -b>
          accept_any<yes>
          pdu_length<23622>
        }
        test1 {
          name<test1>
          port<123>
          root<c:\test>
          monitor<yes>
        }
        test2 {
          name<test2>
          port<124>
          root<c:\test>
          monitor<yes>
        }
        test3 {
          name<test3>
          port<125>
          root<c:\test>
          monitor<yes>
        }
      }
      senders
      timeout<30>
    }
  }
'@

# Call the parser
$objects = $sampleData | ConvertFrom-ServerData

# Uncomment to verify the whole result
#$objects | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10

# The parser outputs nested hashtables, so we have to use GetEnumerator() to
# iterate over the key/value pairs.
$objects.'test-server'.store.servers.GetEnumerator().ForEach{
    "[ SERVER: $($_.Key) ]"
    # Convert server values hashtable to PSCustomObject for better output formatting
    [PSCustomObject] $_.Value | Format-List
}
```

**Output:**

```text
[ SERVER: * ]

value      : 
port       : 
folder     : C:\windows
monitor    : True
args       : -T -H
xrg        : store
wysargs    : -t -g -b
accept_any : True
pdu_length : 23622


[ SERVER: test1 ]

name    : test1
port    : 123
root    : c:\test
monitor : True


[ SERVER: test2 ]

name    : test2
port    : 124
root    : c:\test
monitor : True


[ SERVER: test3 ]

name    : test3
port    : 125
root    : c:\test
monitor : True
```

**Notes:**

- I have further relaxed the regular expressions. Keys may now consist of any character except whitespace, `<`, `>`, `{` and `}`.
- Line breaks are no longer required. This is more flexible but you can't have strings with embedded `>` characters. Let me know if this is a problem.
- I have added detection of invalid tokens, which are output as warnings. Remove the `"(?<Invalid>\S+)"` line, if you want to ignore invalid tokens instead.
- Unbalanced curly braces are detected and reported as error.
- You can see how the RegEx works and get explanations at [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/wbvoot/1).

**C# version:**

- I've since created a faster [C# version of the parser](https://gist.github.com/zett42/6dc8867cec5c2310ccf9aeb87f2ddf16).
- It requires PowerShell 7+. It can be imported using `Add-Type -Path FileName.cs` and called like `[zett42.ServerDataParser]::Parse($text)`.
- It doesn't use RegEx. It is based on `ReadOnlySpan<char>` and uses only simple string operations. In the benchmarks I did it was about 10x faster than a C# version that used RegEx and about 60x faster than the PS-only version.

Comment: So good! I know you have more than answered the question, I did come across two strange cases-

1.) Now it will only work if the first key (ie test-server in your new example) has a hyphen, removing it will throw an error, I tried my best but could not figure out how to solve this.

2.) In certain cases some of the server entries have a comment child 'key' example: comment< this is a date 2/2/2022>

This will also cause it not to be captured. I can probably use regex to just remove these comments, as I have no idea how to capture them :) 

Thanks!

Comment: So good! I know you have more than answered the question, I did come across two strange cases-

1.) Now it will only work if the first key (ie test-server in your new example) has a hyphen, removing it will throw an error, I tried my best but could not figure out how to solve this.

2.) In certain cases some of the server entries have a comment child 'key' example: comment< this is a date 2/2/2022>

This will also cause it not to be captured. Not sure if this is an easy fix - I can probably use regex to just remove these comments, as I just have no idea how to capture them :) 

Thanks!

Comment: @Bajan I just tested first key without hyphen and it works for me. Have you adjusted the query accordingly? `$objects.'test-server'.store.servers.GetEnumerator()` becomes `$objects.testserver.store.servers.GetEnumerator()`. If you don't know the first key in advance you can write `$objects[0].store.servers.GetEnumerator()`. This works because `$objects` is an ordered hashtables which support access by index.

Comment: `comment< this is a date 2/2/2022>` is working too for me. It gets parsed like a string key. Can you post a full example where it doesn't work?

Comment: Hello!

I tested using your code above with the following sampledata:
https://pastebin.com/GTU3HW87

Comment: @Bajan With this data I get error "Exception calling "Pop" with "0" argument(s): "Stack empty.", which means that `{` and `}` are not balanced. There is an additional `}` after each comment, which propably shouldn't be there. When these are removed, it parses correctly.

Comment: @Bajan I've added detection of unbalanced curly braces, so you get a more meaningful error message.

Comment: Such great work on this, it's truly appreciated! Yes I can see that there is a mismatch of braces!

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that converts the above configfile into dict/json in python. I'm just doing some regex as @zett42 suggested.

```
import re
import json

lines = open('configfile', 'r').read()

# Quotations around the keys (next 3 lines)
lines2 = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z\d_*]+)\s?{', r'"\1": {', lines)
# Process k<v> as Key, Value pairs 
lines3 = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z\d_*]+)\s?<([^<]*)>', r'"\1": "\2"', lines2) 
# Process single key word on the line as Key, value pair with empty value
lines4 = re.sub(r'^\s*([a-zA-Z\d_*]+)\s*$', r'"\1": ""', lines3, flags=re.MULTILINE)

# Insert replace \n with commas in lines ending with "
lines5 = re.sub(r'"\n', '",', lines4)

# Remove the comma before the closing bracket
lines6 = re.sub(r',\s*}', '}', lines5)

# Remove quotes from numerical values
lines7 = re.sub(r'"(\d+)"', r'\1', lines6)

# Add commas after closing brackets when needed
lines8 = re.sub(r'[ \t\r\f]+(?!-)', '', lines7)
lines9 = re.sub(r'(?<=})\n(?=")', r",\n", lines8)

# Enclose in brackets and escape backslash for json parsing
lines10 = '{' + lines9.replace('\\', '\\\\') + '}'

j = json.JSONDecoder().decode(lines10)
```

Edit:
Here's an alternative that may be a little cleaner

```
# Replace line with just key with key<>
lines2 = re.sub(r'^([^{<>}]+)$', r'\1<>', lines, flags=re.MULTILINE)
# Remove spaces not within <>
lines3 = re.sub(r'\s(?!.*?>)|\s(?![^<]+>)', '', lines2, flags=re.MULTILINE)
# Quotations
lines4 = re.sub(r'([^{<>}]+)(?={)', r'"\1":', lines3)
lines5 = re.sub(r'([^:{<>}]+)<([^{<>}]*)>', r'"\1":"\2"', lines4)
# Add commas
lines6 = re.sub(r'(?<=")"(?!")', ',"', lines5)
lines7 = re.sub(r'}(?!}|$)', '},', lines6)
# Remove quotes from numbers
lines8 = re.sub(r'"(\d+)"', r'\1', lines7)
# Escape \
lines9 = '{' + re.sub(r'\\', r'\\\\', lines8) + '}'
```

Comment: Nice one! Great to see that my idea works out. Seems to be a good approach when the input data is not too different from JSON. Compared to that, a full-fledged parser is more code. Nevertheless I did just that, which was a good exercise. It might also come in handy as a template for more complex parsing requirements.

Comment: This is fantastic! Great job, I think for my use case it might be easier to use the PowerShell version now that I have had a chance to come back to the issue again! I appreciate your time taken to provide this!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I've since come up with a [much simpler, PowerShell-only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72274775/7571258) which I recommend to use.

I'll keep this answer alive as it might still be useful for other scenarios. Also there are propably differences in performance (I haven't measured).

---

[MYousefi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1991397/myousefi) already posted a [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72234367/revisions) with a Python implementation.

For **PowerShell**, I've come up with a solution that works without a convert-to-JSON step. Instead, I've adopted and generalized the [RegEx-based tokenizer code](https://github.com/Vanlightly/DslParser) from Jack Vanlightly (also see [related blog post](https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2016/2/24/a-more-efficient-regex-tokenizer)). A *tokenizer* (aka *lexer*) splits and categorizes the elements of the input text and outputs a flat stream of *tokens* (categories) and related data. A *parser* can use these as input to create a structured representation of the input text.

The tokenizer is written in generic C# and can be used for any input that can be split using RegEx. The C# code is included in PowerShell using the `Add-Type` command, so no C# compiler is required.

The parser function `ConvertFrom-ServerData` is written in PowerShell for simplicity. You only use the parser directly, so you don't have to know anything about the tokenizer C# code. If you want to adopt the code to different input, you should only have to modify the PowerShell parser code.

Save the following file in the same directory as the PowerShell script:

**"RegExTokenizer.cs":**

```cs
// Generic, precedence-based RegEx tokenizer.
// This code is based on https://github.com/Vanlightly/DslParser 
// from Jack Vanlightly (https://jack-vanlightly.com).
// Modifications:
// - Interface improved for ease-of-use from PowerShell.
// - Return all groups from the RegEx match instead of just the value. This simplifies parsing of key/value pairs by requiring only a single token definition.
// - Some code simplifications, e. g. replacing "for" loops by "foreach".

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace DslTokenizer {
    public class DslToken<TokenType> {
        public TokenType Token { get; set; }
        public GroupCollection Groups { get; set; }
    }

    public class TokenMatch<TokenType> {
        public TokenType Token { get; set; }
        public GroupCollection Groups { get; set; }
        public int StartIndex { get; set; }
        public int EndIndex { get; set; }
        public int Precedence { get; set; }
    }

    public class TokenDefinition<TokenType> {
        private Regex _regex;
        private readonly TokenType _returnsToken;
        private readonly int _precedence;

        public TokenDefinition( TokenType returnsToken, string regexPattern, int precedence ) {
            _regex = new Regex( regexPattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled );
            _returnsToken = returnsToken;
            _precedence = precedence;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TokenMatch<TokenType>> FindMatches( string inputString ) {

            foreach( Match match in _regex.Matches( inputString ) ) {
                yield return new TokenMatch<TokenType>() {
                    StartIndex = match.Index,
                    EndIndex   = match.Index + match.Length,
                    Token      = _returnsToken,
                    Groups     = match.Groups,
                    Precedence = _precedence
                };
            }
        }
    }

    public class PrecedenceBasedRegexTokenizer<TokenType> {

        private List<TokenDefinition<TokenType>> _tokenDefinitions = new List<TokenDefinition<TokenType>>();

        public PrecedenceBasedRegexTokenizer() {}

        public PrecedenceBasedRegexTokenizer( IEnumerable<TokenDefinition<TokenType>> tokenDefinitions ) {
            _tokenDefinitions = tokenDefinitions.ToList();
        }

        // Easy-to-use interface as alternative to constructor that takes an IEnumerable.
        public void AddTokenDef( TokenType returnsToken, string regexPattern, int precedence = 0 ) {
            _tokenDefinitions.Add( new TokenDefinition<TokenType>( returnsToken, regexPattern, precedence ) );
        }

        public IEnumerable<DslToken<TokenType>> Tokenize( string lqlText ) {

            var tokenMatches = FindTokenMatches( lqlText );

            var groupedByIndex = tokenMatches.GroupBy( x => x.StartIndex )
                .OrderBy( x => x.Key )
                .ToList();

            TokenMatch<TokenType> lastMatch = null;

            foreach( var match in groupedByIndex ) {

                var bestMatch = match.OrderBy( x => x.Precedence ).First();
                if( lastMatch != null && bestMatch.StartIndex < lastMatch.EndIndex ) {
                    continue;
                }

                yield return new DslToken<TokenType>(){ Token = bestMatch.Token, Groups = bestMatch.Groups };

                lastMatch = bestMatch;
            }
        }

        private List<TokenMatch<TokenType>> FindTokenMatches( string lqlText ) {

            var tokenMatches = new List<TokenMatch<TokenType>>();

            foreach( var tokenDefinition in _tokenDefinitions ) {
                tokenMatches.AddRange( tokenDefinition.FindMatches( lqlText ).ToList() );
            }
            return tokenMatches;
        }
    }        
}
```

**Parser function written in PowerShell:**

```sh
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

Add-Type -TypeDefinition (Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\RegExTokenizer.cs -Raw)

Function ConvertFrom-ServerData {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] [string] $InputObject
    )

    begin {
        # Define the kind of possible tokens.
        enum ServerDataTokens {
            ObjectBegin
            ObjectEnd
            ValueInt
            ValueBool
            ValueString
            KeyOnly
        }
        
        # Create an instance of the tokenizer from "RegExTokenizer.cs".
        $tokenizer = [DslTokenizer.PrecedenceBasedRegexTokenizer[ServerDataTokens]]::new()

        # Define a RegEx for each token where 1st group matches key and 2nd matches value (if any).
        # To resolve ambiguities, most specific RegEx must come first 
        # (e. g. ValueInt line must come before ValueString line).
        # Alternatively pass a 3rd integer parameter that defines the precedence.        
        $tokenizer.AddTokenDef( [ServerDataTokens]::ObjectBegin, '^\s*([\w*]+)\s*{' )
        $tokenizer.AddTokenDef( [ServerDataTokens]::ObjectEnd,   '^\s*}\s*$' )
        $tokenizer.AddTokenDef( [ServerDataTokens]::ValueInt,    '^\s*(\w+)\s*<([+-]?\d+)>\s*$' )
        $tokenizer.AddTokenDef( [ServerDataTokens]::ValueBool,   '^\s*(\w+)\s*<(yes|no)>\s*$' )
        $tokenizer.AddTokenDef( [ServerDataTokens]::ValueString, '^\s*(\w+)\s*<(.*)>\s*$' )
        $tokenizer.AddTokenDef( [ServerDataTokens]::KeyOnly,     '^\s*(\w+)\s*$' )
    }

    process {
        # Output is an ordered hashtable
        $outputObject = [ordered] @{}

        $curObject = $outputObject

        # A stack is used to keep track of nested objects.
        $stack = [Collections.Stack]::new()
        
        # For each token produced by the tokenizer
        $tokenizer.Tokenize( $InputObject ).ForEach{
        
            # $_.Groups[0] is the full match, which we discard by assigning to $null 
            $null, $key, $value = $_.Groups.Value
            
            switch( $_.Token ) {
                ([ServerDataTokens]::ObjectBegin) {  
                    $child = [ordered] @{} 
                    $curObject[ $key ] = $child
                    $stack.Push( $curObject )
                    $curObject = $child
                    break
                }
                ([ServerDataTokens]::ObjectEnd) {
                    $curObject = $stack.Pop()
                    break
                }
                ([ServerDataTokens]::ValueInt) {
                    $intValue = 0
                    $curObject[ $key ] = if( [int]::TryParse( $value, [ref] $intValue ) ) { $intValue } else { $value }
                    break
                }
                ([ServerDataTokens]::ValueBool) {
                    $curObject[ $key ] = $value -eq 'yes'
                    break
                }
                ([ServerDataTokens]::ValueString) {
                    $curObject[ $key ] = $value
                    break
                }
                ([ServerDataTokens]::KeyOnly) {
                    $curObject[ $key ] = $null
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        $outputObject  # Implicit output
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```sh
$sampleData = @'
servername {
    store {
      servers {
        * {
          value<>
          port<>
          folder<C:\windows>
          monitor<yes>
          args<-T -H>
          xrg<store>
          wysargs<-t -g -b>
          accept_any<yes>
          pdu_length<23622>
        }
        test1 {
          name<test1>
          port<123>
          root<c:\test>
          monitor<yes>
        }
        test2 {
          name<test2>
          port<124>
          root<c:\test>
          monitor<yes>
        }
        test3 {
          name<test3>
          port<125>
          root<c:\test>
          monitor<yes>
        }
      }
      senders
      timeout<30>
    }
  }
'@

# Call the parser
$objects = $sampleData | ConvertFrom-ServerData

# The parser outputs nested hashtables, so we have to use GetEnumerator() to
# iterate over the key/value pairs.

$objects.servername.store.servers.GetEnumerator().ForEach{
    "[ SERVER: $($_.Key) ]"
    # Convert server values hashtable to PSCustomObject for better output formatting
    [PSCustomObject] $_.Value | Format-List
}
```

**Output:**

```text
[ SERVER: * ]

value      : 
port       : 
folder     : C:\windows
monitor    : True      
args       : -T -H     
xrg        : store     
wysargs    : -t -g -b  
accept_any : True      
pdu_length : 23622     


[ SERVER: test1 ]      

name    : test1        
port    : 123
root    : c:\test      
monitor : True


[ SERVER: test2 ]      

name    : test2        
port    : 124
root    : c:\test      
monitor : True


[ SERVER: test3 ]

name    : test3
port    : 125
root    : c:\test
monitor : True
```

**Notes:**

- If you pass input from `Get-Content` to the parser, make sure to use parameter `-Raw`, e. g. `$objects = Get-Content input.cfg -Raw | ConvertFrom-ServerData`. Otherwise the parser would try to parse each input line on its own.
- I've opted to convert "yes"/"no" values to `bool`, so they output as "True"/"False". Remove the line `$tokenizer.AddTokenDef( 'ValueBool', ...` to parse them as `string` instead and output as-is.
- Keys without values `<>` (the "senders" in the example) are stored as keys with value `$null`.
- The RegEx's enforce that values can be single-line only (as the sample data suggests). This allows us to have embedded `>` characters without the need to escape them.

Comment: This literally blew my mind, I need to take some time to learn regex properly. This is honestly incredible.

I have taken a couple of hours playing around and trying to work my way around your code. 

Example - I figured out to use '^\s*([\w*|-]+)\s*{' for the ObjectBegin to capture servers with a hyphen in the name.

Comment: I just can't seem to figure out how I can modify it to work in cases where the config file *doesn't* start with

servername {
    store {
      servers {
        * {


Example it does not work if the start of the document is:


test-server {
    something {
      foo {
        * {

Even though I have tested side by side in an online regex parser highlighter and it seems to highlight and capture the same exact text fields in both cases, it simply won't work!

Any idea?

Thank you once again!

Comment: @Bajan This works for me to allow hyphen in servername: `([\w*\-]+)\s*{`. This one works too, it is the most relaxed one, allowing any non-whitespace characters: `(\S+)\s*{`. I've also removed the line begin anchoring `^`, it's not really necessary.

Comment: Nice, yes that might be ideal for my scenario for using the more relaxed case...

Any thoughts on why it is not capturing correctly when the config file starts with something other than:

    servername {
    store {
 servers {
     * {


Ie, 


server-name {
    store-test {
 servers-test {
     * {


Does NOT work in my testing for some reason when I replace the first 4 lines of the config with something else

Comment: @Bajan Try with my [new, simplified code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72274775/7571258) which further relaxes the RegEx's.

Comment: @Bajan The new code still had a serious bug, which is now resolved. I've also added detection of invalid tokens and improved performance of repeated calls to `ConvertFrom-ServerData`. It turns out that calling the static `[RegEx]::Matches()` function is faster than using a RegEx instance method in this case.